# How to fetch file from github url in yocto?

Tags: github, yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I am trying to fetch file from github releases but it is saying not found?
The recipe i am using is something like this below.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Description of package"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"


MY_DESTINATION = "${libdir}/folder"



#SRC_URI = "file://file.zip"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/latest/file.zip;protocol=file"


S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install_append() {
         install -d ${D}${MY_DESTINATION}
         cp -r ${S}/file/* ${D}${MY_DESTINATION}
}

FILES_${PN} += "${MY_DESTINATION}/*"
```

Can somebody please help what i am doing wrong here?

Errors are following...

```
ERROR: repo-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export GIT_PROXY_COMMAND="oe-git-proxy"; export NO_PROXY="*"; export PATH="/work/build/tmp-glibc/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/work/openembedded-core/scripts:/work/build/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-oe-linux-gnueabi.......
https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/latest/file.zip
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.121.4
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-07-14 09:22:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.


ERROR: repo-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/latest/file.zip;protocol=http'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

Comment: Your source dir S is probably wrong: there are many recipes in poky/openembedded-core that do this exact thing that you can use as examples. If you need more help you should include the error message: what exactly is not found? at what stage of the build?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen i have updated the question. I have defined the folder name as "file" it takes only file folder from the source..

Comment: It is obvious that this link is invalid `https://github.com/user/repo/releases/download/latest/file.zip` , you can test it on a browser it will give you `Not Found` , please set a correct link to a real gitHub user, project and release

Comment: No.I already tested it with my browser. It downloads the zip file

Comment: You tested in a browser that is not logged in to github? (in other words, is this a private repo?)

Comment: Yes it is a private repo and my account was logged in.

Comment: If i take the source code and compile it with bitbake from the same repo it works. but getting the zip file from releases does'nt work. Seems like Github SSH credentials doesnt work for releases?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that fetches a release from a `GitHub` project:

```
SUMMARY = "RTCOS (Run To Completion Operating System)"
LICENSE = "MIT"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/kaizoku-oh/rtcos/archive/refs/tags/1.2.3.zip;protocol=http"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "37e7c1303db943e56e603e9ec699235b"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "e86ee36e8716fe4b33be9bcb272ef9835c5e5ec3b58fd3e2c681334175945e4b"
```

Steps:

1. Go to projects releases
2. Select a release and copy the Link of `Source code (zip)`
3. Add it to SRC_URI
4. The protocol should be `http`
5. Now, bitbake will get the md5 and sha256 sum for you in an error, copy them to your recipe

**More recipe enhancements:**

You can set the release link depends on the version number of the recipe, like this:

```
SRC_URI = "https://github.com/kaizoku-oh/rtcos/archive/refs/tags/${PV}.zip;protocol=http"
```

with that, name the recipe to the same name as the project:

```
rtcos_1.2.3.bb
```

Now the release will be automatically fetched based on your recipe version, of course you need to change the checksum whenever `bitbake` will complain about it.

Now, Yocto will unpack the package into `${WORKDIR}/recipe_name-release_version`, for my example it will be:

```
${WORKDIR}/rtcos-1.2.3
```

So set your ${S} variable to that, you can set it dynamic:

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/${PN}-${PV}"
```

**PN**: Package name

**PV**: Package version

Now you can copy the content to you `MY_DESTINATION`:

```
MY_DESTINATION = "${libdir}/folder"

do_install(){
   install -d ${D}${MY_DESTINATION}
   cp -r ${S}/* ${D}${MY_DESTINATION}
}

FILES_${PN} += "${MY_DESTINATION}/*"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. your recipe looks absolutely correct. but i still have that not found error. I have updated my question. And i am really confused why i am getting this error. :(

Comment: I gave you a GitHub example so you can follow it on your real GitHub release.